# ligthning:treeGrid Column: how to print related field Name value

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How do I print Related(Lookup) field name value in the lightning:treeGrid columns?

Columns:

```
{
  type: 'text',
  fieldName: 'Site_Located__r.Name',
  label: 'Site'
}
```

JS:

```
 if (state === "SUCCESS" ) {
                var resultData = response.getReturnValue();
                for (var i=0; i<resultData.length; i++ ) {
                    resultData[i]._children = resultData[i]['OpportunityIWS__r']; 
                    delete resultData[i].OpportunityIWS__r; 
                }
                component.set('v.gridData', resultData);
            }
```

SOQL:

```
oppList = [SELECT Id, Name,StageName,
                       (SELECT Name,Stage__c,Specialty__c,Site_Located__c,Site_Located__r.Name,SeatsConfirmed__c FROM OpportunityIWS__r)
                       FROM Opportunity Where Id =: OppId];
```

This one is printing as NULL.

I am able to print only the ID with "**Site_Location__c**", not the name. I am also quering this **Site_Located__r.Name** in SOQL

[image]

Response:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the treegrid example. The documentation explains how to show _children records related to the parent. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_treeGrid.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you print the response from Apex in your JS, you will see something as below:

```
{Id: "xyzaaaaa", field1: "val1", field2: "val2", Site_location__c: "abcdxxxxx", Site_location___r: {Name: "The Site Name"}}
```

The structure of the response is that for every Site_Location__c (which is the id of the record), it then has an additional details under Site_Location__r. So you will need to fetch the details from that information by traversing through the JSON response. Once you receive the response from Apex, you will need to add a logic to fetch details as:

```
var data = response.getReturnValue(); // the response from Apex
for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
     // fetch the site related information
     var site = data[i]['Site_Location__r'];

     // get the field in consideration, let's say Name
     // assign it to a new variable and add it to the JSON response
     data[i].SiteName = site.Name;
 }
 cmp.set('v.gridData', data);
```

Finally, while declaring the columns for the tree grid, add a column to show the field as set in the JS function as:

```
{
    type: 'text',
    fieldName: 'SiteName', // variable as set on the response as in JS function above
    label: 'Site Name'
}
```

You can use this logic for any related field that you may have retrieved.

**UPDATE:**
Based on your latest information, you can still use the same approach to retrieve the values from the response. You need to print the response in console to see how you can retrieve the additional details. So, in your example where you have list of child records for Opportunity, your code

```
resultData[i]['OpportunityIWS__r'];
```

will return a list of records. You will then additionally need to iterate over that list to fetch the values and set it on a custom field that you need to define at the column level of the data. Your code will look like:

```
var opptyIWS = resultData[i]['OpportunityIWS__r']; // opptyIWS is an array of child records
data[i].SiteName = opptyIWS[0].Name // as an example, fetches the Name from the first record.
```

Comment: In my case, bit different, because parent is Opportunity, and then child is Custom object, so from custom object related field I have to get the Site Name. I update the description with additional details for reference.

Comment: Print the response from soql in console. That will give you exactly what you need to retrieve from the response to be able to get the field required.

Comment: Added details on how you can retrieve the details from the array of child records that you will receive in the response. The example just retrieves the Site Name of the first child record from the array. So you will need to iterate over the array to fetch and set values accordingly.

Comment: I can get the value till "resultData[i]._children" here after that, not able to read "resultData[i]._children.Site_Located__r.Name"

Comment: *resultData[i]._children* will return an array. So you will need to fetch the Name as *resultData[i]._children[0].Name* -- this will give you the Site Name of the first record in the children, and so on.

Comment: No, resultData[i]._children[0].Name, this is not working. [Cannot read property '0' of undefined]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76155/discussion-between-jayant-das-and-ajay).

Comment: Hey guys I am having the exact same issue but I cannot figure out what your final answer was from your chat. Can you update your answer or question with the final version of the controller?